# Companion object in Scala isn't associating itself with case class

Tags: scala, object, factory, apply

I'm having some trouble understanding why this code won't work. I got it from 99 Scala Problems in the Binary Trees section (http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/). It looks valid to me: the Node object is a companion object to the Node class, and it's adding a constructor for leafs on the tree. But when I try compiling it, I get the following:

```
<console>:10: error: too many arguments for method apply: (value: T)Node[T] in object Node

    def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = Node(value, End, End)
```

If I remove both Ends, I don't get any compile errors, but if I make a Node with a single value I get stuck in an infinite loop. So it looks like apply is constructing more Node objects, and isn't associating itself with the Node class.

Any help is appreciated.

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T]
case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {
    override def toString = "T(" + value.toString + " " + left.toString + " " + right.toString + ")"
}
case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
    override def toString = "."
}
object Node {
    def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = Node(value, End, End)
}
```

Comment: scalac compiles it well from the source file. I'm pretty sure this is just a console issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works for me (see below). Have you defined them in the same file?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed abstract class Tree[+T]
case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {
    override def toString = "T(" + value.toString + " " + left.toString + " " + right.toString + ")"
}
case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
    override def toString = "."
}
object Node {
    def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = Node(value, End, End)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Tree
defined class Node
defined module End
defined module Node

scala> Node("123")
res0: Node[java.lang.String] = T(123 . .)

scala>
```

**Edit**
From your comment: it looks like the `:load` command in the repl interprets each line in the file one by one, you can find the code for that [here](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ILoop.scala#L218). However this doesn't work using the REPL since (I believe) each line that is interpreted gets compiled in its own package. See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/9d86380b971bb8ac?pli=1) for more details. Perhaps this could be a future enhancement in the REPL. But in principle, there is nothing wrong with your code: using both `:paste` mode or just compiling with `scalac` works fine.

```
scala> case class A(i: Int, i2: Int)
defined class A

scala> object A {
     | def apply(i: Int): A = A(i, i)
     | }
:25: error: too many arguments for method apply: (i: Int)A in object A
       def apply(i: Int): A = A(i, i)

scala> object A {
         def apply(i: Int): A = new A(i, i)
       }
defined module A
warning: previously defined class A is not a companion to object A.
Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.
```

**N.B.** I couldn't find any enhancement request on JIRA, so I created [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4684)

Comment: It works in paste mode, but not when I run ":load ./tree.scala" in scala console. Not sure what the difference is.